# Creating guestbook and getting "mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given > in"

Tags: php

I am making a guestbook rightnow and its not 100% working. I am getting these errors here:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given
>   in C:\MAMP\htdocs\guestbook\addguestbook.php on line 23
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in C:\MAMP\htdocs\guestbook\addguestbook.php on line 24

And here you can see my code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'database');

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

$datetime = date("y-m-d h:i:s"); //date time

$sql = "INSERT INTO guestbook (name, email, comment, datetime)VALUES('$name', '$email', '" . nl2br(htmlspecialchars($comment)) . "', '$datetime')";
$intodatabase = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE comment='$comment'";
$check = mysqli_query($sql, $user_check_query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($check);

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    if ($count > 0) {
        if ($result) {
            echo "Erfolgreich";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<a href='viewguestbook.php'>Show</a>";

        } else {
            echo "Connection Error";
        }
        echo "<a href='guestbook.php'>user name already in use</p>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Inkorekte E-Mail";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<a href='guestbook.php'>try again</a>";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Look for the difference between your two calls to `mysqli_query`.

Comment: You accidentally used the SQL string from the first query instead of your connection object.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, now i a getting: 
"Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\MAMP\htdocs\guestbook\addguestbook.php on line 24"

Comment: If you get a boolean it means your query failed. You should set your mysqli connection up to throw exceptions on SQL errors so you can see why.

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments

Comment: Perfect, thank you alot dude!

Comment: You're welcome! Also, you should bind those post values as parameters to prepared statements. The way you're concatenating them with the SQL string is vulnerable to SQL injection. Here's an example from the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.execute-examples

Comment: Ok i will take a look at that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your `$sql` variable into your `mysqli_query()` function when you are supposed to be passing `$intodatabase`.